# How to send back-end variables to angular 2

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular

How to send back end variable to angular 2 with out using API calls.

1. using Asp.net core

my cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var message = "@ViewBag.Message";
  console.log(message);
</script>

@Html.Hidden("mesg", (string)ViewBag.Message);
```

want to send message/ hidden field value angular 2, how?

2. using node.js

`app.post('/something', (req,res) => {
 message = req.body.Message
 });`

want to send message variable to angular 2, how?

Answer (score 0):

You want the server to push data to the client. You can achieve it using websockets protocol. SignalR is an implementation by microsoft if you are into using .net.

It basically keeps a live connection to the server and server can send data directly to a client. Unlike a normal HTTP where there is no connection kept alive just a request and response occurs, web sockets allow a bi-directional connection to be kept alive for this happen.

node js there are tons of implementaiton. 
Some protocols node js can use to accomplish this is : MQTT,AMQP,WAMP

I have used [autobahn/crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) implementation of websockets(wamp) and it works awesome.

Here's a [proper article about Websockets.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Try it out. [Here's an example library that implements websockets directly](https://github.com/websockets/ws).
Note: The links mentioned above is not related in any way to me. These are good links I used myself in the past.

Comment: any example(link) for this. to make it better understand  fast.

Comment: Added a link to article and a github link of the implementation. This will be really useful to you I believe

Comment: it is not good for authentication token purpose(guess), cause we can expect lot of request per sec at that time it may cause problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure it can handle it.... If you don't want to handle it directly... look at pubnub.com they do a good job at it...  Remember that FCM and most push notification service now use these kind of protocols. Most lightweight among them is MQTT protocol...

Comment: Another way you can handle it is using long-polling ( hitting the server every few seconds).... I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: Will try it for authentication purporse. seen the express.js code  `ws.send('something');` how could I catch it in client side(angular 2) ? any idea?

Comment: Well the link i gave you was for backend. heres a github link on how to handle it in the front end. As long as its the same protocol, using different libraries on frontend/backend would be fine, but I do suggest finding a common one if you can. https://github.com/PeterKassenaar/ng2-websockets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149976/discussion-between-k11k2-and-narendran-pandian).